# The Auth for Office 365 REST API

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, office365

I try to use Office365 REST API to list user's files (OneDrive for Business or SharePoint Online), and it can access Office365 administrator account,

but when I try to access other normal active users (who are created by adminstrator account in the Office365 admin center), it could not login, the OAuth page display "**Sorry, but we're having trouble signing you in. We received a bad request.**"

Request headers:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/login HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Cookie: flight-uxoptin=true; stsservicecookie=ests; x-ms-gateway-slice=productiona
Referer: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=2d4d11a2-f814-46a7-890a-274a72a7309e&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.contoso.com%2Fcontoso.htm&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.office.com%2Fdiscovery%2F
Accept-Language: en-US
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Length: 1032
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache

login=example@contoso.onmicrosoft.com&passwd=contoso&ctx=rQIIAdNiNtQztFIxNjY3S00yT9NNTLM01zUxMzLWTUoBcpMMTBOTTZMMTdOSE4uEuAT6rjdUsz8977Uh-YA6807eOasYNTJKSgqKrfT1y8vL9coz86oyC_SS83P1k3PyS1OKU4vKMpNTi_UySnJ3MDJeYGR8wch4i4nf37G0JMMIROQXZValPsIQmcTMn58IEtEDkcn5KamrmBVhNiUWZOrlp6UBDQbblJJZnJxfllpUqb-JmQ0okJuft4tZxSTJ2MTI2NxI18DQwkjXxNI8WdcyOTlR19jCxNLA0Nw4MTEl5QYz4wUWxl2cRPsBAA2&flowToken=AAABAAEAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLRx6Haiauf3FLxlg3g9UORjSbd3XCCl2tfMhe0xEbC2UOYMMPyfYW9aXLIkJZC5nAK7l4G0_2DB-BItK0rx9ueogAA&n1=109320&n2=-1442391510000&n3=-1442391510000&n4=109320&n5=109320&n6=109320&n7=109320&n8=NaN&n9=109320&n10=110226&n11=111404&n12=111404&n13=111406&n14=113261&n15=27&n16=113500&n17=113502&n18=113511&n19=1235&n20=1&n21=0&n22=0&n23=0&n24=0&n25=0&n26=0&n27=0&n28=0&n29=-1442391623258&n30=-1442391623258&n31=0&n32=0&n33=0&n34=0&n35=0&n36=0&n37=0&n38=0&n39=0&n40=0&n41=0&n42=1442391623292&n43=1442391623511&type=11&LoginOptions=3&NewUser=1&idsbho=1&PwdPad=&sso=&vv=&uiver=1&i12=1&i13=MSIE&i14=9.0&i15=520&i16=770&i20=
```

Response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Expires: -1
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
x-ms-request-id: ab3393a8-0cde-4767-bd12-a2f4cd0be32c
client-request-id: 7b80d78e-e507-4acf-b063-c02703b90d9c
x-ms-gateway-service-instanceid: ESTSFE_IN_164
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
P3P: CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN"
Set-Cookie: x-ms-gateway-slice=productiona; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: stsservicecookie=ests; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 16 Sep 2015 08:20:32 GMT
Content-Length: 2206
```

I follow the below OAuth flow
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx

Any idea what the problem is and how this can be resolved? I would really appreciate somebody's help with this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you share what platform you're working on and your auth code? Those login values you posted are just placeholders, right? You're not actually sending example@contoso.onmicrosft.com?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution in the blow link

http://blog.beecomedigital.com/2015/06/08/aadsts90093-calling-principal-cannot-consent-due-to-lack-of-permissions/

BTW,
It is difficult to understand why the "Bad Request" message is displayed without anyother error message in the OAuth page.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the scope parameter missing that caused this issue. Looks like you must include scope when sending authorization request.